# Can we integrate the cypress with Jenkins build job

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to know how we can setup cypress in Jenkins. Do we have specific steps for that? I faced many issues while installing cypress on my machine in the office network.

Thanks

Comment: It may be easier to find answer if you describe your attempts and the issues you got

Answer (score 3):

Cypress has documentation and examples for all major CI providers, including Jenkins: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html

Here is an example Jenkinsfile for the Cypress example project:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/Jenkinsfile